# Not allowed to use cons on list; "does not match any of the declared (overloaded) signature patterns"

Tags: rascal

According to this page:

http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascalopedia/List/List.html

This is how you use cons on lists:

```
cons(1,[2,3]); //should return [1,2,3]
```

Trying this in the Rascal console:

```
import List;
cons(1,[2,3]);
```

Gives me this error:

```
|stdin:///|(1,13,<1,1>,<1,14>): The called signature: cons(int, list[int]),
does not match any of the declared (overloaded) signature patterns:
    Symbol = cons(Symbol,str,list[Symbol])
    Production = cons(Symbol,list[Symbol],set[Attr])
    Symbol = cons(Symbol,str,list[Symbol])
    Production = cons(Symbol,list[Symbol],set[Attr])
```

Is there some name collision with the standard imported functions and datatypes?

Comment: did we answer your question Guildenstern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. First a straightforward answer. Cons does not exist as a library function for constructing lists (it is rather a part of the reified types API meaning something different).

We write this:

```
rascal>[1, *[2,3,4]]
list[int]: [1,2,3,4]

rascal>1 + [2,3,4]
list[int]: [1,2,3,4]

rascal>[1] + [2,3,4]
list[int]: [1,2,3,4]

rascal>list[int] myList(int i) = [0..i];
list[int] (int): list[int] myList(int);

rascal>[*myList(10), *myList(20)]
list[int]: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

Now an explanation for the confusion. The Rascalopedia course is on abstract concepts and terms typically good to know when working with Rascal. This may be too basic for you. I would focus on the Rascal language and libraries course for more concrete examples and information relevant to programming in Rascal. See http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/List/List.html for the list literals and http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/List/List.html for library functions on lists.

Some other list handiness, used for deconstructing as opposed to constructing:

```
rascal>[1,2,3,4][1..]
list[int]: [2,3,4]

rascal>[1,2,3,4][1..2]
list[int]: [2]

rascal>[1,2,3,4][..-1]
list[int]: [1,2,3]

rascal>if ([*x, *y] := [1,2,3,4], size(x) == size(y)) println(<x,y>);
<[1,2],[3,4]>
ok

rascal>for ([*x, *y] := [1,2,3,4]) println(<x,y>);
<[],[1,2,3,4]>
<[1],[2,3,4]>
<[1,2],[3,4]>
<[1,2,3],[4]>
<[1,2,3,4],[]>
```

Comment: What is the motivation of overloading `+` to mean both construction and concatenation.  In my opinion, this not only contradicts the static-typing concept of the language (`1 + [2]` should induces an type error!), but also sets a pit for users to fall as indicated [here](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/List/Insert/Insert.html)

Comment: The motivation was that we thought we had too many operators already and Rascal was beginning to feel like Perl, but we have come back from this lately. The next version of Rascal will have `<<` and `>>` operators for adding elements to sets, lists, (or something similar, and not ambiguous with the rest of the language). The good thing about an "alpha" language, we can still change it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Oh, then you guys probably should put an alpha tag on Rascal's home page so that users are aware that the language may be subject to future incompatible changes!  Honestly, I only learned this fact now, after I have written a Lisp interpreter in Rascal.  Although it is not intended to be released as a standalone application (I doubt this is possible until the Rascal compiler is ready.), it is annoying to see my code break later.  I think it is important that you summarize these changes whenever a new version of Rascal is released.

Comment: Makes sense to put an "alpha" tag indeed. See http://www.rascal-mpl.org/about/ for our disclaimer. Changes that are truly radical are not expected and we hope to provide good feedback mechanisms if the language changes.